# What is best practice to deal with XML input parameter in SQL Server

Tags: c#, xml, sql-server-2008

In one of my c# project, i have to store multiple rows in database table . For that i passed Xml data as a string datatype in stored procedure and after that i changed back to XML and then using sp_xml_prepareddocument i stored into table.

I am wondering whether this is a correct approach. Or is there any other best approach available to handle this scenario. Is there any performance loss when XML will big.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertData]
 @nSiteId int,
 @nClaimId int,
 @nEditSourceId int,
 @sClaimEditXml NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE @hDoc INT, @nRC INT  
    EXEC @nRC = sp_xml_preparedocument @hDoc OUTPUT, @sClaimEditXml  
    IF @nRC <> 0  
    BEGIN  
        RAISERROR( N'apiInsertClaimCurrentEdits #1', 16, -1 )  
        RETURN -1  
    END

    IF EXISTS(SELECT * from ClaimCurrentEdits where SiteID=@nSiteId and ClaimID=@nClaimId and EditSourceId = @nEditSourceId)
    BEGIN
        DELETE FROM ClaimCurrentEdits where SiteID=@nSiteId and ClaimID=@nClaimId and EditSourceId = @nEditSourceId 
    END

    INSERT INTO [ClaimCurrentEdits]
   ([SiteID]
   ,[ClaimID]
   ,[ErrorID]           
   ,[ErrorDesc]
   ,[Severity]
   ,[ValidationDate]
   ,[EditSourceId]
   )     
    SELECT * FROM OPENXML( @hDoc, '/ValidationResults/ValidationResult',2 )
    WITH
    (   SiteId int '../@SiteId',
        ClaimId int '../@ClaimId',
        ErrorId int '@ErrorId',
        ErrorDesc varchar(2048) '@ErrorDesc',
        Severity int '@Severity',
        ValidationDate datetime '@ValidationDate',
        EditSourceId int '@EditSourceId'
    )   

    EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @hDoc

END

RETURN 0

/******************************************************************************/

GO
```

Answer (score 0):

If you xml is going to be on the large side, OpenXML is the route to go as long as you make sure to run the sp_xml_removedocument as soon as you are done. If you are going to see smaller chunks on xml, I think XQuery is faster and does not bring to the table any of the memory concerns from sp_xml_preparedocument.

I have always found that trying both methods with a valid size of xml for your needs is the best approach.